# angularjs: $watch not triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

trying to do something simple here.

In my controller:

```
  $scope.testObject = { name : 'john' };

  $scope.$watch('$scope.testObject.name', function (e, n, v) {
      console.log('reached');
  });
```

In my view:

```
  <input type="text"  ng-model="testObject.name"/>
```

The textbox is bound to the testObject's name property and when the controller is loaded, the code goes into the $watch function.

Now, if I edit the textbox value, the $watch function is never triggered. Why is that ?

I've also tried setting the third argument of $watch to true, with no effects.

Comment: Should `$scope.testObject.name` be in quotes inside the `$watch` function?

Comment: Maybe this will help clear some confusion http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the $scope from your watch. It should read as:

```
$scope.$watch('testObject.name', function(e,n,v){
    console.log("reached");
});
```

Comment: ok, that works, thanks. But I don't understand why it worked at controller initialization and not after.... does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$scope.$watch('testObject.name', function(e,n,v){
    console.log("reached");
});
```

You can also add other observer like this:

```
$scope.$watch('testObject.attr1 + testObject.attr2', function(e,n,v){
    console.log("reached");
});
```

or:

```
$scope.$watch('testObject', function(e,n,v){
    console.log("reached");
}, true);
```